# Is KES rotation operation time sensitive? Does the datetime of the offline machine need to be set correctly?

Tags: stake-pool

Talking about `key-gen-KES` and `issue-op-cert` operations of `cardano-cli`.
Does the output of these functions depends on the machine clock?

They are part of [rotating the KES process](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node#18-1-rotate-pools-kes-keys-updating-the-operational-cert-with-a-new-kes-period) of which one of the steps if performed on an off-line machine, meaning no NTP time synchronization over the network. And if we combine that we no battery on the off-line machine that we get a date time that is far from current.

Hence my question. Do the KES rotating operation need to be performed on machines that have date and time set correctly? Can the offline machine clock be off by hours? days? months?

```
   cardano-cli node key-gen-KES \
        --verification-key-file kes.vkey \
        --signing-key-file kes.skey
```

and

```
cardano-cli node issue-op-cert \
    --kes-verification-key-file kes.vkey \
    --cold-signing-key-file $HOME/cold-keys/node.skey \
    --operational-certificate-issue-counter $HOME/cold-keys/node.counter \
    --kes-period <startKesPeriod> \
    --out-file node.cert
```

I did a quick search on the [`cardano-node` Github repo](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node) for both
[key-gen-KES](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/search?q=issue-op-cert) and [issue-op-cert](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/search?q=issue-op-cert) but I am not familiarized with the cardano-node codebase enough to make any sense of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notion of time is based on the input **startKesPeriod**, which is taken from the most current KES period of the blockchain.

You get the current KES period by dividing current slot number of the blockchain with the **slotsPerKESPeriod** parameter.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, obviously but this is an explicit input. I should have been more verbose in my question perhaps as it is the implicit inputs that I am concerned about. Not the explicit ones that users provide themselves. In other words, can you tell if the only datetime reference that is needed for either of these two operations is the kesperiod?

Comment: That's a great question. I've done some research, but without fully understanding the code behind cardano-cli, I can't say for sure. Hope someone from IOG will answer this.